# Mean(or other function) of corresponding elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list, each element in this list is a vector and have same length. I want to calculate the mean(or other value, it can be a user-defined function) of all first element of each vector, mean(or other value, it can be a user-defined function) of all second element of each vector, etc. And return a vector. So this is different from question [How to sum a numeric list elements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939813/how-to-sum-a-numeric-list-elements-in-r) .Following code gave me the exactly what I want, however, is there any more efficient and sophistical way to do this? Thanks.

```
list1 <- list(a=1:5,b=2:6,c=3:7)
result <- numeric(length(list1[[1]]))
for(i in 1:length(list1[[1]])){
  result[i] <- mean(c(list1[[1]][i],list1[[2]][i],list1[[3]][i])) #the function can be any other function rather than mean()
}
```

Comment: I would do `library(data.table); sapply(transpose(list1), mean)`, but that requires a package. Maybe `colMeans( do.call(rbind, list1) )`..?

Comment: Thanks @Frank, I just wonder is there anyway to finish this without any additional package?

Comment: `Reduce("+",list1)/length(list1)`

Comment: @paqmo that is a very brilliant solution, you should post it. You have my up vote.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24478531/ Yeah, I like the Reduce way.

Comment: @SabDeM thanks! done!

Comment: @DavidLee - In R the goal is to access the underlying C/Fortran routines as quickly as possible; the fewer functions calls required to achieve this, the better. 

Suppose x is a standard vector of length n. Then
`x = x + 1`
involves a single function call to the + function. Whereas the for loop

`for(i in seq_len(n))
  x[i] = x[i] + 1`

has n function calls to `+`; `[` function;  `[<-` function (used in the assignment operation); A function call to `for` and to the `:` operator.

It isn’t that the for loop is slow, rather it has more function calls. 
Ref: Efficient R Programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option using the `Reduce` function:

```
Reduce("+",list1)/length(list1)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting them all in a matrix and then calculating the means of the columns?

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, list1))

[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```